# Is there a datatype that uses less storage for 2 letters than String?

Tags: java, string, letter

Basically what the title says. I'm aware that i could use char as type if i only had one letter, but i need a datatype for 2 letters, e.g "XY". Is there anything that uses less storage (bit) or is smaller than a String? Or are multiple letters generally just saved as Strings? Thanks!

Comment: What about `char[2]`?

Comment: For ASCII letters, you could even squeeze them into a single `char`. More info about the intended use would be helpful. I mean, if these are ASCII letters, then all possible combinations would only occupy a few KBbytes anyhow...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are sure that there are no higher-unicode characters (i.e. characters that use more than 1 char to store) in use, there are a few options:

- As mentioned by @rdas, you could use an array: `char[2]`. This would be a bit more memory-efficient than a String, as the String has additional members. If it's only ASCII-characters, you could even use `byte[2]`.
- As one char is 16 bits, 2 chars are 32 bits, so could also try to encode the 2 characters into 1 int, as this also uses only 32 bytes, and you would not have the object overhead of the array. Clearly, this requires some additional steps to encode/decode when you need to show the stored information as actual characters, e.g. when presenting it to the user.
- If your characters are only ASCII codes, i.e. every character fits into 1 byte, you could even fit it into a short.
- Depending on the number of two-character combinations that you actually need to support, you could actually just enumerate all the possible combinations, use a lookup Map or sorted Array, and then only store the number/index of the code. Again, depending on the number of combinations, use a byte, short or int.

Answer (score 0):

No it is not possible

This is why::
String s = "ab" // uses only 4 bytes of data as each character reserves 2 bytes

And other data types uses >= 4 bytes except short and byte but here short and byte cannot store characters